# insert value of a variable into database using tclodbc

Tags: tcl

Using tclodbc with the `revnum` variable containing `77777`,
the following statement gets the error “`ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "$revnum"`”

```
$db {insert into (revnum,risetime,settime,sat,passlen,riseges,setges,elevation)
    values('$revnum','1111-11-1111:11:11:11','1111-11-1111:11:11','C4','24','QQ','QQ','22');}
```

But this statement works:

```
$db {insert into (revnum,risetime,settime,sat,passlen,riseges,setges,elevation)
    values('77777','1111-11-11 :11','1111-11-1111:11:11','C4','24','QQ','QQ','22');}
```

Why wont the the value of the variable `revnum` insert into the database?

Comment: `$revnum` isn't being interpolated so the database gets `$revnum` where it expects an integer. I don't know enough TCL to show you how to do it properly though. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2194381/479863) might help though.

Comment: Better retag as "tclodbc" rather than "postgresql" as the question per se has nothing to do with the indicated DBMS implementation.

Answer (score 3):

mu is too short gave a correct answer: the solution is to learn how [grouping](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl3.html) of characters [works](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl4.html) in Tcl before trying to insert something to a database.

*But* note well that your code is inherently flawed because you do not use paraterized queries, which is what every sensible programmer is supposed to use when querying the database programmatically. Read about the `statement` subcommand of a database object in the tclodbc manual. Basically you should do:

```
$db statement ins {insert into (revnum, risetime, settime, sat,
                                passlen, riseges, setges, elevation)
                   values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}
$ins $revnum 1111-11-1111:11:11:11 C4 24 QQ QQ 22
```

That way, the ODBC backend driver takes care of properly escaping all the values preventing [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) no matter where the values come from and what they contain.

Comment: If it was possible to use `tdbc::odbc`, that would make this even easier.

Comment: I should add that [TDBC](http://tdbc.tcl.tk) has a native PostgreSQL driver so if using TDBC is an option, one could use `tdbc::postgres` right away.

Comment: As a slight comment, parameterized queries are where a sensible programmer should go *first*, but there are cases where they're not a realistic option. For example, when inserting many rows it can be inconvenient at best to do so.

Comment: @RHSeeger When inserting many rows is exactly where you want a parameterized query (with appropriate wrapping of a transaction, checkpoints, etc.) The main contra-indication for parameterization is when you've got to have some generated non-value parts of the SQL (e.g., table names or field names). Those _can't_ be parameterized (well, not without a stored procedure to act as a thunk/shim).

Comment: The problem I've run into with parameterized queries is when you want to do something of the form [insert into mytable (x,y,z) values (1,2,3),(3,4,5),,,,,(100,101,102)]. Specifically, when you have lots of value elements. When you're building the list from lists of list with joins, it seems hard to use them.