# what is the different use of " " and {}

Tags: tcl

When I want to implement a my own procedure I have one doubt. For example, the following is OK:

```
% proc + {a b} {expr $a+$b}
% + 3 4
7
```

But when we are using "" instead of {}:

```
% proc + "a b" "expr $a+$b"
```

it will give this error:

```
can't read "a": no such variable
```

At the same time when we use \ it gives an answer:

```
% proc + "a b" "expr \$a+\$b"
```

Here, \ not considered $ as a special char then it will take as $a and it look same as the second example. Can anybody tell me the difference between these three methods of defining a proc?

Comment: I'm a little foggy on what this has to do with digital certificates...

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2193641/7552), the [syntax rules of Tcl](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm) and the [Tcl tutorial](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html)

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental difference between quotes and curly braces is that variables are expanded inside of quotes, but not in curly braces. In the final example, when you place a backslash in front of the dollar sign, it removes the special nature of the dollar sign, thus the variable isn't initially expanded.

This is all explained on the [Tcl man page](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/Tcl.htm). That single page is a remarkably concise and accurate description of the language.