# Tcl: Evaluate the variable value when passing argument to class

Tags: tcl

I have a piece of code like this

```
oo::class create class_test {
    variable title_text
    variable result
    method title {t} {
        set title_text $t
        set result [format "%-6s %-6s" {*}$title_text]
    }
    method print {} {
        return $result
    }
}

set a "abcde"
set b "fghij"
class_test create foo
foo title {"$a" "$b"}
puts [foo print]
```

The real output is

```
$a     $b
```

While the expected output is

```
abcde  efghi
```

Could someone help to fix it?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/2193641/7552

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
foo title {"$a" "$b"}
```

to

```
foo title [list $a $b]
```

so that the variables get substituted by their values.

Answer (score 1):

You want to expand substitutions inside a `{`brace-quoted`}` string (logically) after the point that it is written in the script. This isn't usually recommended (not when you can construct arguments with `list` correctly), but you *can* do it.

```
method title {t} {
    set title_text [lmap value $t {
        uplevel 1 [list subst $value]
    }]
    set result [format "%-6s %-6s" {*}$title_text]
}
```

We do the transform on each word in the argument (`lmap`) and the transform is to apply `subst` to it, which must be done in the caller's context (`uplevel 1`). The use of `list` in there is so that we guarantee that we make a substitution-free script to run in the outer context, a ***very* strongly recommended practice**.

---

A feature of TclOO is that you don't need to take special precautions to use `uplevel` (or `upvar`) when using it, unlike some other older object systems for Tcl. That makes doing this sort of thing in a method no more tricky than doing it in a normal procedure. This is true even when inheritance is present.

Comment: I only rewrote the `title` method; the rest of the script should be identical.

Comment: Maybe it's the best way, because people can use this script as usual。

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone help to fix it?

I fail to see why you, first, pack variable references into a single value and, then, uplevel-substitute them. In addition, the number of value arguments to `format` seem fixed. Why not just use two separate formal parameters to your `title` method and use them directly?

```
method title {v1 v2} {
    set result [format "%-6s %-6s" $v1 $v2]
}
```

Then just call it like so:

```
foo title $a $b
```

### Update

> to generate the title in different length

then better use `args` like so?

```
method title {args} {
    set result [format [join [lrepeat [llength $args] "%-6s"] " "] {*}$args]
}
```

`args` is the natural way of having a method (proc) with variable arguments in Tcl.

Comment: what I want to do is to gengerate the title in different length, which means the number of arguments varies from different situations.

Comment: Yeah, but if I exec directly `foo title {"$a" "$b"}`, I will come across the problem I'm asking. Shawn has shown the right way for me. Thank you anyway.

Comment: You would execute the following for `args` to work: `foo title $a $b`.